# MeCabのユーザ辞書作成後、RMeCabで登録した内容が反映されない

Tags: mecab

環境はWIndows10です。
MeCabのユーザ辞書を作成するために、以下のようなcsvファイルをutf-8で作成し、"C:\95CI.csv" に保存しました。

```
95%信頼区間,1285,1285,5000,名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,95%信頼区間,キュウジュウウゴパーセントシンライクカン,キュージューゴパーセントシンライクカン
```

その後コマンドプロンプトにて以下を実行

```
C:\Program Files\MeCab\bin> mecab-dict-index.exe -d "C:\Program Files\MeCab\dic\ipadic" -u 95CI.dic -f utf-8 -t uft-8 "C:\95CI.csv"
reading C:\95CI.csv ... 1
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|

done!
```

"C:\Program Files\MeCab\etc\mecabrc" の末尾に以下の記述を加えました。

```
userdic = C:\95CI.dic
```

これらの後RStudio上で形態素解析を行ったところ、95％信頼区間が分割されて形態素解析されます。

丸１日ハマっているのでどなたか解決策をご存知でしたらご教示いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 指定するべき 95CI.dic ですよね。うまくいくことを確認してないのと、書き損じも考えられたのでひとまずコメントで

Comment: >quickquipさん　書き損じ失礼しました。mecabrcでは95CI.dicを指定しています。

Answer (score 0):

RMeCab で利用する際には、改めて辞書の指定が必要なんじゃないでしょうか。

https://rmecab.jp/wiki/index.php?MeCab_Dictionary

> なお RMeCab 上で辞書を指定するには関数で dic 引数を指定します
>
> ```
> > library(RMeCab)
> > x <- docMatrix("/Users/ishida/tmp", dic = "/Users/ishida/R/data/ishida.dic")
> ```

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
> RMeCabC("今日は95％信頼区間の求め方を勉強します", dic ="C:/95CI.dic")を実行したところ
95％信頼区間は途中で区切られて形態素解析されました。
辞書の指定の仕方が間違っているのでしょうか。

Comment: `*.csv` はあくまで「辞書作成時の元ファイル」なので、指定すべきは `*.dic` じゃないでしょうか。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。　ご指摘の通りmacabrc、RMeCab ともに`*.dic`を指定しているのですが、分割されて形態素解析されます。